# Fix Facebook sdk path

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm editing a .php file that will run on my XAMPP installation.
The file has to connect to Facebook when it's launched and, next, post a text message on a FB user profile.

To do this, I've followed the guidelines on this official page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/5.0.0

Specifically, I've follow the "Manually installing (if you really have to)" procedure. It's ok, but when I launch my script, I obtain this error:

*Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Octopus\index.php on line 31*

Here's my code, where I've insert some fake auth credentials:

```
<?php
//require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
//require_once __DIR__ . '\vendor\autoload.php';
//echo __DIR__ . '\vendor\autoload.php';

/*if (($loader = require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php') == null)  
{
  die('Vendor directory not found, Please run composer install.');
}
*/
// require Facebook PHP SDK
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/
// require_once("/YOUR_PATH_TO/facebook_php_sdk/facebook.php");
//require_once(__DIR__ . '\vendor\facebook\php-sdk-v4\src\facebook.php');

// initialize Facebook class using your own Facebook App credentials
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/#install


require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$config = array();
//$config['appId'] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
//$config['secret'] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';



$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

 $fb = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '43629645236452943',
  'secret' => '385628354628075362783654728365',
));

//$fb = new Facebook($config);

// INIZIO SESSIONE DI REPERIMENTO TOKEN
session_start();
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('{callback-url}', '{app-id}', '{app-secret}');

try 
{
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} 
catch(FacebookSDKException $e) 
{
    $session = null;
}

if ($session) {
  // User logged in, get the AccessToken entity.
  $accessToken = $session->getAccessToken();
  // Exchange the short-lived token for a long-lived token.
  $longLivedAccessToken = $accessToken->extend();
  // Now store the long-lived token in the database
  // . . . $db->store($longLivedAccessToken);
  // Make calls to Graph with the long-lived token.
  // . . . 
} else {
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login with Facebook</a>';
} 
// FINE SESSIONE 

// define your POST parameters (replace with your own values)

// "access_token" => "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN", // see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

$params = array(
  "access_token" => $accessToken, // see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
  "message" => "Here is a blog post about auto posting on Facebook using PHP #php #facebook",
  "link" => "http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php",
  "picture" => "http://i.imgur.com/lHkOsiH.png",
  "name" => "How to Auto Post on Facebook with PHP",
  "caption" => "www.pontikis.net",
  "description" => "Automatically post on Facebook with PHP using Facebook PHP SDK. How to create a Facebook app. Obtain and extend Facebook access tokens. Cron automation."
);

// post to Facebook
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/
try {
  //$ret = $fb->api('/YOUR_FACEBOOK_ID/feed', 'POST', $params);
  $ret = $fb->api('/MY_FACEBOOK_PROFILE/feed', 'POST', $params);
  echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

In this image, a screen of my root folder:
[Facebook path problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENM0V.png)

Can you help me? Why the facebook object isn't instantiable?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also add the namespace.

The code for it in one of my project:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $app_id,
    'app_secret' => $app_secret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @BarneyK, your suggest has solved my problem. 
I have now an error on line 49 of my code: 

    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('{callback-url}', '{app-id}', '{app-secret}');

Is it the same thing of above?

Comment: I don't think so, because you included by "use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;". The error is still "Class xy not found"?

Comment: I solved by using this pathname: $helper = new Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('{callback-url}', '{app-id}', '{app-secret}'); How can I get callback-url?

Comment: Tha callback-url is an url on your site, where you want to redirect your user after login.
For example: FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('mypage.com/after_login.php',$appid, $appsecret');
Btw. Can you accept my answer please? :)

Comment: The problem is that every url I insert in FacebookRedirectLoginHelper causes the generation of this error: 
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\Authentication\OAuth2Client, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Octopus\index.php on line 50 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Octopus\facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0\src\Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php on line 77. Please note that I'm working in localhost with the script